# Call second API if first one timeouts after given amount of time in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe, timeout

If my API is not returning data in let's say 5 seconds I have to call another one.
I tried to achieve it like this:

```
this.service.returnData1(param1, param2)
.pipe(timeout(5000), finalize(() => this.callSecondApi()))
.subscribe(
  data => {
    this.myList = data.filter(item => !this.removeStuffFromList(item, data));
    if (this.myList.length > 0) {
      //do some other stuff
      this.originalList = this.myList;
    }
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
 )

callSecondApi(){
this.service.returnData2(param1, param2).subscribe(
   data1 => {
        this.myList = data1.filter(item => !this.removeStuffFromList(item, data1));
        }
        if (this.myList.length > 0) {
           this.originalList = this.myList;
        }
      },
      (err) => console.log(err.message)
   )
  }
```

What is the best approach to solve this ? I also tried different answers with switchMap, tap, mergeMap but nothing seemed to work mostly because I have to add that timeout on the first subscribe. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably not use `finalize`, since you only want to switch to observe the second API call once the first one has failed (or timed out). Therefore you should just use `catchError` operator to switch to another observable:

```
this.service
  .returnData1('param1', 'param2')
  .pipe(
    timeout(5000),
    catchError((err) => callSecondApi())
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: (data) => {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: (err) => {
      console.log(err.message);
    },
  });
```

**Note:** Passing separate functions to a `subscribe` call is deprecated. I instead used an observer object.

Comment: I don’t hink your last statement is fully correct, only certain signatures are deprecated. Just mentioning this to not confuse people reading your answer. More here: https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/subscribe-arguments

Comment: Well, isn‘t this what I stated? I said passing separate functions is deprecated, therefore I used an observer object. If you have a more clear explanation, feel free to edit my answer. Any help is appreciated!